# Does using different Divine names in prayer have practical consequences and effects?

Tags: tefilla, mysticism-kabbalah, shemos-sacred-names

It is well known that there are different names for G-d, blessed be He, even shown in the Torah itself, where different references to Him emphasize different relations and attributes.

Having said that, is there a practical consequence or effect of using different Divine names in prayer? By that, I mean if someone prays for something, would the result of what they receive (if anything) be different if they used a different Divine name?